# Asp.net file upload validation with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using the below jquery function to do client side validation for an asp.net file upload control.

```
function setUplaodButtonState() {
    var maxFileSize = 4096000 // 4MB -> 4000 * 1024
    var fileUplaod = $("#<%=flupldSignUpDocuments.ClientID%>");

    if (fileUplaod.val() == '') {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (fileUplaod[0].files[0].size < maxFileSize) {
            $("#<%=lblfilesizerror.ClientID%>").html("");
            return true;
        } else {
            $("#<%=lblfilesizerror.ClientID%>").text('File is Larger than recommended size');

            var file = document.getElementById("<%=flupldSignUpDocuments.ClientID%>");
            $(file).parent().html($(file).parent().html());

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The first time a user uploads a file greater that the specified file size the error is shown and also the fileupload box is cleared of any content. However, on trying the second time around with the same file that is greater than the recommended size the box is not cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to the fact that you're replacing the file upload control's html entirely and replacing it with its own html. This way you're removing all attached (js) event handlers. You could try the jQuery clone() method, it has a parameter for cloning a control including the event handlers and attached data.

Something like this:

```
var clone = $(file).clone(true);
var parent = $(file).parent();
parent.html("");
parent.append(clone);
```

There is prob. a shorter way to code this, but you get the idea.